# Python interact with dolphin emulator

Tags: python, python-2.7, emulation

I have a game in dolphin and I am trying to make a python program that can interact with it and I wrote the following code using the library https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput.

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()
m.click(131, 289) #makes the dolphin window the current window
k.tap_key('O')    # presses the O key
```

This code will work on all the programs I have tried. But it does not work for some emulators. Is there something I am doing wrong or can this library just not interact with the dolphin emulator. If this library does not work could someone tell me a library or way to make python code simulate a keyboard press for the dolphin emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this fork of mine that lets you run embedded python scripts: https://github.com/felk/dolphin/

For example, to rapidly press A on a gamecube game, you can do the following:

```py
from dolphin import controller, event

while True:
    await event.frameadvance()
    buttons = controller.get_gc_buttons(0)
    buttons["A"] = True
    controller.set_gc_buttons(0, buttons)
    await event.frameadvance()
    # do nothing every other frame
```

The embedded python includes a full standard library, so you can try opening a socket or http server to make it communicate with some external program.

Comment: oh, I just noticed this question is 5 years old, I somehow missed that...

Comment: Unfortunately in 2015 the dolphin emulator did not have the ability to interface with it using a socket, so that "import dolphin" wasnt possible. I think they added it in 2019. Your solution works though. so thanks